# Не переприсваивается значение переменной

Tags: java, android

Тут, вроде, все очень-очень просто, но у меня все равно возникли трудности.
В `xml` разметке лежит `Chronometer`. В `mainActivity` есть булева переменная `a = false`, которая является т.н. счетчиком нажатий.
По нажатию на `Chronometer`, если `a == false`, `Chronometer` присваивает себе значение переменной `elapsedMillis`, запускается (начинает отсчет) и переменной `a` присваивается значение `true`. По второму нажатию, ставит `Chronometer` на паузу, присваивает переменной `a` значение `false` и записывает в переменную `elapsedMillis` текущее время. При этом при первом нажатии `Chronometer`-у присваивается значение переменной `elapsedMillis`.
Так вот, проблема в том, что переменной `elapsedMillis`, если `a == true` не присваивается новое значение

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
    boolean  a = false;
    Chronometer mChronometer;`

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        mChronometer = (Chronometer) findViewById(R.id.chronometer);

    }
    public void onClick(View view) {
        long elapsedMillis = SystemClock.elapsedRealtime();

        if (!a){
            mChronometer.setBase(elapsedMillis);
            mChronometer.start();
            a=true;
        }
        else {
            elapsedMillis = (SystemClock.elapsedRealtime() - mChronometer.getBase())/1000; // Тут кроется проблема!!!
            //System.out.println(elapsedMillis); // Забавно, но время выводится правильно
            mChronometer.stop(); // это скорее пауза, чем стоп. И пауза только "визуальная" - программно отсчет продолжается.
            a=false;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: А дебаг метода пробовали? Что показывает в переменной а?

Comment: Переменная а работает корректно, т.к. по второму нажатию таймер ставится на паузу

Comment: А что если вынести переменную elapsedRealtime в поле класса?  Т.е. объявить ее под Chronometer?

Comment: В таком случае переменная elapsedRealtime вместо значения 0, которое она принимала на прежнем месте, принимает какие-то очень странные значения

Comment: То есть она определена под Chronometer, в обработчике нажатия в первой строке (где сейчас определяется) ей присваивается значение и оно странное? Или переменная определяется сразу со значением? Думаю стоит просто определять и в onClick уже присваивать значение

Comment: Сначала я просто определяю ее в поле класса, и задаю ей значение равное SystemClock.elapsedRealtime(), которое должно быть равно 0.Потом в ОнКлике я задаю Хронометру значение переменной  elapsedMills и вывожу его в консоль. Получаю значение равное 8 миллионам.

Comment: Давайте [продолжим обсуждение в чате](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/40418/discussion-between-igor-gorokhov-and-andrew-paramoshkin).